# Regex: выбрать только третью строку (пометить определенную линию)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Я работаю в Notepad++.

Предположим, я хочу выбрать только третью линию, чтобы заменить её другой во многих документах с помощью функции `Заменить в файлах`.

Пробовал использовать

```
\A^(.*){2}.*$
```

К сожалению, это выражение находит не только третью, но и последующие строки в многострочном документе.

PS: [Этот вопрос по-английски.](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39426603/regex-select-only-the-line-3-mark-particular-line)

Comment: Приведите пример входных данных и выходных данных, которые вы хотите получить. Ваш вопрос не совсем прозрачен в понимании.

Comment: А не проще ли воспользоваться Seek, который есть почти во всех языках программирования и перейти на 3 строчку, а потом делать с ней, что угодно?

Comment: /^[^\n]*\n[^/n]*\n([^\n]*)\n/\1/

Comment: Я попытался это  \A(^.*?){2}^.*$  но не работает  Я использую Notepad ++

Comment: практически я хочу, чтобы соответствовать определенной линии

Comment: check the solution here  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39426603/regex-select-only-the-line-3-mark-particular-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в Notepad++ поиск с помощью регулярных выражений работает циклически при использовании массовой (глобальной) замены. Заменив 3-ю строку, индекс расположен вновь в начале, и 6-я строка становится 3-й и т.д.

В данном случае, нужно найти совпадение, равным всему документу. Вы можете воспользоваться

```
\A((?:.*\R){2}).*((?s:.*))\z
```

В качестве шаблона замены можно использовать `$1Моя_новая_строка$2`.

Подробности:

- `\A` - начало документа
- `((?:.*\R){2})` - Захватывающая группа (подмаска) №1, осуществляющая поиск 2 последовательностей нуля и более символов, отличных от знака перевода строки, за которой следует знак перевода строки (перыве две строки)
- `.*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от знака перевода строки (то, что будет заменено)
- `((?s:.*))` - 2-я захватывающая группа, которая находит любые 0 и более знаков до....
- `\z` - конца документа.

`$1`  - обратная ссылка на содержание 1-й захватывающей подмаски.